# How to match lines not ending (-1)\r\n

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to match the first 5 lines, and the last line, in this sample:

```
-- 2012-09-20 rep +6    = 184       
 1  12532070 (2)
 2  12531806 (5)
 2  12531806 (5)
-- 2012-09-21 rep +12   = 196       
 3  125xxxxx (-1)
 3  125xxxxx (-1)
 16 12557052 (2)
```

Leaving the following unmatched:

```
 3  125xxxxx (-1)
 3  125xxxxx (-1)
```

I've tried the following regular expressions:

```
^.*[^(-1)\r\n].*
^.*[^(-1)].*\r\n
^.*[^\(-1\)\r\n].*
^.*[^\(\-1\)\r\n].*
^.*[?!\(-1)\r\n].*
^(!?.*-1.*\r\n)
```

But none of them do what I want (mostly matching *all* lines).

My RegEx skills are not brilliant - can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: which language-tool are you using..regex implementation differs across languages

Comment: @Anirudh Sorry, I hadn't realised RegEx is specific to the language. I'm using Notepad++'s find and replace feature. Sorry about that, I've retagged my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead

```
^(?!.*\(-1\)$).*$\r\n
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett i said it,the regex should be used with multiline option,which tool-language are you using

Comment: @DannyBeckett `\r\n` after `$` is not right! `$` depicts the end of line and anything after that has no use

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to create a regular expression for this, I would just use the surrounding language to negate the sense of the match, and use a regex that *only* matches lines that end in '(-1)\r\n'.  For instance:

Shell:  `grep -v '(-1)^M$'`

Perl:   `!/\(-1\)\r\n/`

Ed/Vi:  `v/(-1)^M$`

etc.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised RegEx is specific to the language. I'm using Notepad++'s find and replace feature. Sorry about that, I've retagged my question.